# How to index a MySQL InnoDB table to query with select ... where key in ( some values here)?

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb, innodb, explain

I have a mariadb 10.3 server, and the following table (using InnoDB storage engine):

```
create table if not exists token (
   `token` bigint unsigned not null,
    `uid` smallint unsigned not null default 0,
    `nham` int default 0,
    `nspam` int default 0,
    `timestamp` int unsigned default 0
) Engine=InnoDB;

create index token_idx1 on token(token);
create index token_idx2 on token(uid);
```

The token table has ~900k rows, and I'd like to execute the following query with a 2-300 numbers in the `IN ( )` clause:

```
select token, nham, nspam from token where token in (1,2,3,4,...);
```

Now the problem: the query executes very slowly, and it just won't use `token_idx1`:

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  id  | select_type | table | type | possible_keys |     key    | key_len |  ref  |  rows  |    Extra    |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|   1  |    SIMPLE   | token |  ref |   token_idx1  | token_idx1 |    2    | const | 837534 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

Since the token column is indexed, I'm surprised that explain select says that the optimizer has no interest on `token_idx1` (and the query takes a long time, ~30 sec due to the full table scan).

How to fix the issue? I'm aware that I could use USE `INDEX(token_idx1)` in the query, but I'd solve it without such hack.

Comment: I cannot imagine that an in statement consisting of 300 elements is going to be quick. Can you put these into a table and use a join instead?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I did some testing on a table of mine that has a similar index on a column. I only tested with the IN clause, but got interesting results. When I used a list with only valid matches, it went very fast, but when I put an invalid in, it seems to scan the entire table. EXPLAIN verified this behavior.

Comment: Something is wrong -- `key_len = 2`, yet `token` is a `BIGINT UNSIGNED` (which is 8 bytes).  Please verify the `CREATE TABLE`, the indexes and the explain.

Comment: And you really need a `PRIMARY KEY` on the table.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put these 300 items to a separate table. If the column is indexed (as it is), then I expect the query even with 300 items to be pretty fast. See my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to rewrite the query. So while a query like this sucks at performance:

select token, nham, nspam from token where token in (1,2,3,4,...);

The following query is fast as it should be (even if some token values don't exist in the table):

select token, nham, nspam from token where token=1 or token=2 or token=3 or ...;

So the issue is solved, though I still don't understand why the optimizer has a hard time for the first query.

Anyway, thank you for all of your thoughts, ideas and contributions leading me to the workaround.

Comment: The table has ~8-900k records. Usually I search for a few hundred tokens at a time, and perhaps I get half of them back (ie. other tokens don't exist in the table).

Comment: I asked because I saw quite a few questions asking about slow queries but authors forgot that returning several hundred thousand records is slow for multiple reasons :)

Just a hint, I've no idea if you know about it or not: with `EXPLAIN` there's also `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` and `profiling`. For profiling: `SET PROFILING = 1; SELECT ... (your query here); SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1; SET PROFILING = 0;`. It tends to help to track down what part of the server might be the bottleneck.

Answer (score -1):

drop your existing index token_idx1 and recreate with

```
CREATE INDEX token_idx1 ON token(token) USING BTREE;
CREATE INDEX token_idx2 ON token(uid) USING BTREE;
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would help.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't help because the index type is already BTREE